# What have I said vs What did I say

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, past-simple, past-vs-present-perfect

"What did I say?" I come across this line generally.
What is wrong with this line "What have I said?"

Answer (score 1):

When a parent is reminding a child of a previously stated rule, "What have I said?" and "What did I say?" both work:

> What have I said about leaving your clothes on the floor?
>
> What did I say about leaving your clothes on the floor?

However, when someone is wondering what they said to offend people, or humorously suggesting that they may have said something to scare people away, "What did I say?" is the conventional form - not "What have I said?".  I am not sure what is wrong with "What have I said?", but it isn't used in this situation.

On the other hand, if someone is asking whether they've just said something offensive, "Did I say something to offend?" and "Have I said something to offend?" both work.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by rjpond was good. I just wanted to add that using the simple past interrogative means you are referring to one specific utterance in the past. "What did I say" is equivalent to "what was that one specific thing I said." This is the reason that "what have I said" is not used if a person wants the answer to "what was the specific thing I said that offended you."

On the other hand, "what have I said" leaves the possibility open that you may have said more than one thing or the same thing multiple times. For example, if someone said "you often say things that offend me," then the proper question would be, "What have I said that offended you?" Now the answer can be a list of things I've said.

In fact, this is the reason we often hear things like "what have I said about leaving your clothes on the floor?" The implication is that the exasperated parent has said this many times.

The present perfect means there's a possibility of multiplicity or repetition. The simple past is instance-specific.